# Inoffensifs / inoffensives ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord

Bonjour,

Dans *Voyage au bout de la nuit* :

Bientôt il n’y aura plus que des gens et des choses **inoffensifs**, pitoyables et désarmés tout autour de notre passé, rien que des erreurs devenues muettes.

Peut-on écrire *inoffensifs* ici, ou la grammaire aurait attendu *inoffensives* ?

Comment: Oh !! Céline grand phallocrate devant l'éternel ! « des gens et des choses inoffensifs » c'est l'accord dit de « domination masculine » ou dans la grammaire, le masculin l’emporte sur le féminin. Dont la sacro saine sainte Académie Française ne veut pas se débarrasser (ou avec moultes difficultés) et qui pourtant ne pas toujours existé. . .

Comment: @None Merci beaucoup !

Comment: « des gens et des choses inoffensives » est l'accord dit « de proximité ». Qui pouvait aussi se faire du temps de Céline, et s'il avait écrit « des choses et des gens inoffensifs » non seulement il aurait fait l'accord de proximité mais tu ne te serais pas poser la question. Je m'arrête parce que ça va causer des polémiques, sujet brûlant. Mais bravo pour ta remarque !

Comment: T'as réagi avant que je finisse ! Trop long mon commentaire, j'ai dû scinder. Lis ça https://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2012/01/14/genre-le-desaccord_1629145_3246.html (en libre accès je crois, tu me diras sinon) pas tout à fait ton sujet mais dans l'esprit. Si ça t'intéresse on pourra discuter ailleurs.

Comment: sacro sainte, faute de frappe. Qu'on ne me fasse surtout pas dire que cette institution est saine.

Comment: @None Mille mercis pour le lien ! Oui, libre accès, je vais lire !

Comment: tu ne te serais pas pos**é**

Answer (score 3):

La règle d'accord des adjectifs dans la grammaire dite « traditionnelle » est résumée [sur ce site](https://www.maxicours.com/se/cours/l-accord-de-l-adjectif-qualificatif-dans-le-groupe-nominal/) :

> Lorsqu'il qualifie plusieurs noms, l'adjectif qualificatif est toujours au pluriel. Il est féminin pluriel si tous les noms qualifiés sont féminins, il est masculin pluriel si **au moins un des noms**<sup>1</sup> est masculin.

Et donc en écrivant :

> Bientôt il n’y aura plus que des gens et des choses inoffensifs, pitoyables et désarmés tout autour de notre passé, rien que des erreurs devenues muettes.

Céline respecte la règle en vigueur à son époque. Bien entendu, l'eût-il voulu (et c'est quelqu'un qui maniait la langue à merveille et pesait chaque mot) il aurait pu inverser les noms et écrire :

> Bientôt il n’y aura plus que des choses et des gens inoffensifs...

ce qui lui aurait permis au moins d'appliquer [l'accord de proximité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_proximit%C3%A9) et ainsi ne pas juxtaposer un nom féminin avec un adjectif au masculin.

Écrire « des gens et des choses inoffensives », qui te semblait naturel puisque tu as posé la question, est aussi un accord de proximité. Ça aurait été probablement aller un peu trop loin pour Céline, et ça le reste pour beaucoup de nos jours encore.

L'accord de proximité était courant au Moyen-Âge, ce n'est qu'au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle que le masculin a commencé à prendre le pas. Sur le sujet on peut se référer à l'article de la linguiste Lucy Michel *Penser la primauté du masculin – sémantique du genre grammatical, perspectives synchroniques et diachroniques*<sup>2</sup> et dont Wikipedia cite cet extrait :

> c’est au XVII<sup>e</sup> et XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècles qu’apparait la formulation de la règle de primauté du masculin, corrélée à « une certaine conception de la domination masculine, présentée comme essentielle, naturelle et indiscutable ». Elle caractérise ainsi l’évolution des accords, notamment l’accord en genre : « L’accord de proximité, intra-linguistique, cède le pas à un accord par défaut au masculin, fondé sur l’idée non-linguistique que la matrice de l’humain est le mâle ».

Depuis deux décennies environ, l'accord dit de « domination masculine », où le masculin l’emporte sur le féminin, est de plus en plus remis en cause par certains linguistes, mais aussi par le grand public. Je cite quelques articles en vrac, et bien sûr cette sélection est très loin d'être exhaustive :

- Tout d'abord commençons par *[Le Dictionnaire Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/accord-de-l-adjectif-qualificatif-avec-plusieurs-noms-juxtaposes-ou-coordonnes-par-et)* qui, tout en mentionnant l'accord de proximité, et au contraire de cet autre site donnant des éléments de langue française et cité en introduction, précise que « Toutefois, [l'accord de proximité] reste à ce jour minoritaire dans l'usage et reste souvent considéré comme une faute<sup>2</sup>. »
- Un article du *Monde* (2012) [Genre, le désaccord](https://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2012/01/14/genre-le-desaccord_1629145_3246.html).
- Une tribune de 2019  dans *Libération* : [Le masculin l’emporte accord et encore](https://www.liberation.fr/debats/2019/10/27/le-masculin-l-emporte-accord-et-encore_1760053/).
- Une tribune d'enseignantes et enseignants de tous niveaux publiée en 2017 sur *Slate.fr* : [Nous n'enseignerons plus que "le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin".](http://www.slate.fr/story/153492/manifeste-professeurs-professeures-enseignerons-plus-masculin-emporte-sur-le-feminin)
- Une tribune qui avait à l'époque était citée par plusieurs quotidiens et magazines, par exemple [Le Parisien](https://www.leparisien.fr/societe/des-enseignants-refusent-que-le-masculin-l-emporte-sur-le-feminin-08-11-2017-7381113.php), [Ouest-France](https://www.ouest-france.fr/education/enseignement/ce-prof-ne-veut-plus-enseigner-la-regle-du-masculin-qui-l-emporte-sur-le-feminin-5365302).

Je quitte le grand public pour terminer par la toute petite lueur qui transparaît dans cet article de [Michel Serres](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Serres), membre de l'Académie française, publié en 2018 sur le [site de l'Académie Française](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-bataille-ideologique), et où il reconnait que « Peut-être serait-il intéressant parfois d’utiliser l’accord selon le nombre ou la proximité ».

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Téléchargeable [sur cette page](https://www.shs-conferences.org/articles/shsconf/abs/2016/05/shsconf_cmlf2016_04005/shsconf_cmlf2016_04005.html).</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> Donc conseil à ceux qui passent un examen : ne le pratiquez pas.</sup>