# Agreement of adjective “voisines”

Tags: adjectifs

On the Wikipedia page for [pain au lait](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_au_lait), it is written…

> Le pain au lait est un produit commercialisé en boulangerie, sous la forme oblongue ou ronde d'un petit pain, à l'aspect, à la consistance et à la saveur **voisines** de celle de la brioche.

Why is it “voisines” and not “voisins” here? I thought that the adjective voisin should agree with the words aspect, consistance, and saveur here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should indeed according to the current agreement rules but this is a clear example of an *[accord de proximité](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49117/1109)*, whether intentional or not.